# How to save old data in a data class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I am trying to use a data class but I can't figure out how to save the data properly.

I have created a data class:

```
  data class SavedValue( var currentValue:String, var previousValue:String = "")
```

What I want is each time I am want to save a new `currentValue`, the already saved value for `current` is copy to `previousValue` and the new `currentValue` overwrite the `currentValue` field.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should override the `currentValue` setter and set the previous value before setting the new current value.

Answer (score 1):

A data class in Kotlin is not supposed to provide such functionalities, as they are designed to hold data. 
You could just use a simple class.
Nevertheless you can achieve what you want (with or without a data class), but you will have to move `currentValue` inside the class and use a setter (and a getter).
 
In its place use a `private` property like `_currentValue`:

```
data class SavedValue(private var _currentValue: String, var previousValue: String = "") {
    var currentValue: String
        get() = _currentValue
        set(value) {
            previousValue = _currentValue
            _currentValue = value
        }
}
```

This code:

```
val sv = SavedValue("abc")
println("currentValue = ${sv.currentValue} and previousValue = ${sv.previousValue}")
```

will print:

```
currentValue = abc and previousValue =
```

and this:

```
sv.currentValue = "ABC"
println("currentValue = ${sv.currentValue} and previousValue = ${sv.previousValue}")
```

will print:

```
currentValue = ABC and previousValue = abc
```

Also, I think that you need `previousValue` as a *read only* property, right?
So move it too inside the class and make its setter `private`:

```
data class SavedValue(private var _currentValue: String) {
    var _previousValue: String = ""

    var currentValue: String
        get() = _currentValue
        set(value) {
            previousValue = _currentValue
            _currentValue = value
        }

    var previousValue: String
        get() = _previousValue
        private set(value) {
            _previousValue = value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve isn't straight forward using **data class**. Instead, you can use POJO class and use custom setter and getter.

```
class SavedValue(currentValue: String, previousValue: String) {
private var _currentValue: String = currentValue
private var _previousValue: String = previousValue

var currentValue: String
    get() {
        return _currentValue
    }
    set(value) {
        _previousValue = _currentValue
        _currentValue = value
    }

   override fun toString(): String {
       return "SavedValue(_currentValue='$_currentValue', 
      _previousValue='$_previousValue')"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution works fine but if you do not want the third field just to hold the current value you can do:

```
data class SavedValue(var previousValue: String = "") {
    var currentValue: String = ""
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) previousValue = field
            field = value
        }
}
```

E.g.

```
val savedValue = SavedValue()
savedValue.currentValue = "initial value"
println("current: ${savedValue.currentValue} - previous: ${savedValue.previousValue}")
savedValue.currentValue = "second value"
println("current: ${savedValue.currentValue} - previous: ${savedValue.previousValue}")
savedValue.currentValue = "third value"
println("current: ${savedValue.currentValue} - previous: ${savedValue.previousValue}")
```

Outputs:

```sh
I/System.out: current: initial value - previous:
I/System.out: current: second value - previous: initial value
I/System.out: current: third value - previous: second value
```

Or if you want the non-mutable previousValue you'll need the third field:

```
data class SavedValue(private var _previousValue: String = "") {
    var currentValue: String = ""
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) _previousValue = field
            field = value
        }
    val previousValue: String
        get() = _previousValue
}
```